# Email Studio, AB testing with Data Extension Publication Lists

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, email-studio, publicationlist, ab-testing

When AB testing in email studio, am I able to target a publication list within a data extension? It seems as if I am only able to select only the data extension within the AB testing "select recipients" step.

Answer (score 0):

Within the AB testing tool, there is a publication list that follows the selection of the data extension that filters to the publication list level.